# Getting elements/characters to the right of another character

Tags: javascript

I am trying to retrieve the data to the right of ':' or use ':' as a starting point to get the data after. Looking for the right parsing items for this.

```
var test = 'type:input';
```

charAt gives me the location of ':', but how do I then retrieve the 'input' from var test?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `split`:

```
var testAfter = test.split(':')[1];
```

or `substr` with `indexOf`

```
var testAfter = test.substr(test.indexOf(':')+1);
```

or `slice`

```
var testAfter = test.slice(test.indexOf(':')+1);
```

or `match`

```
var testAfter = test.match(/(:)(.+$)/).pop();
```

or `replace`

```
var testAfter = test.replace(/^.+:/,'');
```

if you want to be free to use whatever delimiter, this String extension may do the work:

```
String.prototype.dataAfter = String.prototype.dataAfter ||
   function(delim){
     return this.split(delim)[1];
   };
//usage
var testAfter = test.dataAfter(':');
var test2 = 'type#input';
var testAfter = test2.dataAfter('#');
```

Comment: Thank you. What if I wanted to use ':' as a delimiter, is there a way have var test2 = test[1], ':'; or some type of declaration of delimiter?

Comment: Can you be more specific? In all examples from my answer ':' *is* the delimiter. Or do you mean something else?

Answer (score 2):

What about substr?

```
 var test2 = test.substr(test.indexOf(':')+1); // until end
```